# Select only observations with a date more recent than the 30/6/2021 (dd/mm/yyyy)

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have the following code:

```
Select Tbl.Fromdate, Tbl.Por, Tbl.Porname, Tbl.Bmref3
From(
Select
To_Char(P.Fromdate, 'dd-mm-yyyy') As  Fromdate, P.Por, P.Porname, W.Bmref3,
, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY P.Por ORDER BY P.fromdate DESC) AS rank 
From Tmsdat.Climandatecomps W 
Inner Join Tmsdat.Portfolios P On (W.Porik = P.Porik)
Where 1=1
) Tbl
Where 1=1
And Tbl.Rank = 1
;
```

However, I wish to select only the observations that have a Fromdate more recent than the June 30, 2021. I tried to add `Tbl.Fromdate> '30-06-2021'` to the WHERE clause, but I did not receive the desired results.

Do you have any suggestions?

Thank you in advance.

Best regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would put the condition in the inner query:

```
Select To_Char(P.Fromdate, 'dd-mm-yyyy') As Fromdate, P.Por, P.Porname, W.Bmref3,
       RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY P.Por ORDER BY P.fromdate DESC) AS rank 
From Tmsdat.Climandatecomps W inner join
     Tmsdat.Portfolios P
     On (W.Porik = P.Porik)
Where p.FromDate > date '2021-06-30'
```